# Show Products' Availability on Category Pages

Tags: opencart2.x

I'm working with opencart 2.0 and I need to adjust the availability of products according to the quantity . 
I arrived to do that on product pages but now I have to show products ' availability on category pages as well

Comment: Yeah, so... what's your question? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: how can i show product 's availability on category pages?

Comment: and where is the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your category controller

```
catalog->controller->category.php
```

Here approx line no 231, there would be a array named `$data['products']` replace this one with this code

```
$data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb'       => $image,
    'name'        => $result['name'],
    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
    'price'       => $price,
    'special'     => $special,
    'tax'         => $tax,
    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url),
    'quantity' => $result['quantity'] // add another key for quantity in this array 
);
```

And in category.tpl file in your theme you can access the quantity by this variable under products loop

```
<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>
```

I hope this will help you .:)

Comment: thx for your answer but this will show just the quantity (i mean by this 10 units, 5 units) not the text available, last one ...

Comment: sorry I am not getting you, can you please explain little bit more what you wants exactly ?

Comment: or availability : last one according to the quantity

Comment: so you can try this in tpl file like that .. availability: <?=$product['quantity']; ?>

Comment: this will give me availability: 100 or availability :10 and so on

Comment: You have to print this variable in loop (products loop) in tpl file.

Comment: why can't add this :if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
    $data['stock'] = $result['stock_status'];
   }elseif($product_info['quantity']  == 10) {
    $data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
   } and in the tpl file write <?php echo $stock; ?> even i add  'stock'       => $this->data['stock'], to the $data['products'] array